# Convert FeatureUnion output to Dictionary for DictVectorizer

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to re-create a pipeline from a datacamp tutorial and running into an issue with my pipeline.  I believe the issue I am having is converted the output of FeatureUnion to a dictionary for DictVectorizer.  When I run the below, the code fails, becuase BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin are not defined.  Any guidance on where I am going wrong would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn_pandas import CategoricalImputer
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion, Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score






kidney_feature_names = ['age',
                    'bp',
                    'sg',
                    'al',
                    'su',
                    'rbc',
                    'pc',
                    'pcc',
                    'ba',
                    'bgr',
                    'bu',
                    'sc',
                    'sod',
                    'pot',
                    'hemo',
                    'pcv',
                    'wc',
                    'rc',
                    'htn',
                    'dm',
                    'cad',
                    'appet',
                    'pe',
                    'ane',
                    'class']

kidney_data = pd.read_csv("https://assets.datacamp.com/production/repositories/943/datasets/82c231cd41f92325cf33b78aaa360824e6b599b9/chronic_kidney_disease.csv",
                      names=kidney_feature_names,
                      index_col=False,
                      na_values=["?"])

kidney_data['pcv'] = pd.to_numeric(kidney_data['pcv'], errors='coerce')
kidney_data['wc'] = pd.to_numeric(kidney_data['wc'], errors='coerce')
kidney_data['rc'] = pd.to_numeric(kidney_data['rc'], errors='coerce')
print(kidney_data.dtypes)

#Split data between data and labels
X, y = kidney_data.iloc[:,:-1], kidney_data.iloc[:, -1]

# Check number of nulls in each feature column
nulls_per_column = X.isnull().sum()
print(nulls_per_column)

# Create a boolean mask for categorical columns
categorical_feature_mask = X.dtypes == object
print(categorical_feature_mask)

# Get list of categorical column names
categorical_columns = X.columns[categorical_feature_mask].tolist()
print(categorical_columns)

# Get list of non-categorical column names
non_categorical_columns = X.columns[~categorical_feature_mask].tolist()
print(non_categorical_columns)



# Apply numeric imputer
numeric_imputation_mapper = DataFrameMapper(
                                        [([numeric_feature], SimpleImputer(strategy="median")) for 
numeric_feature in non_categorical_columns],
                                        input_df=True,
                                        df_out=True
                                       )

# Apply categorical imputer
categorical_imputation_mapper = DataFrameMapper(
                                            [(category_feature, CategoricalImputer()) for 
category_feature in categorical_columns],
                                            input_df=True,
                                            df_out=True
                                           )

# Combine the numeric and categorical transformations
numeric_categorical_union = FeatureUnion([
                                      ("num_mapper", numeric_imputation_mapper),
                                      ("cat_mapper", categorical_imputation_mapper)
                                     ])


# Custom transformer to convert Pandas DataFrame into Dict (needed for DictVectorizer)
class Dictifier(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):       
def fit(self, X, y=None):
    return self

def transform(self, X):
    return X.to_dict('records')

# Create full pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline([
                 ("featureunion", numeric_categorical_union),
                 ('dictifier', Dictifier())
                 ("vectorizer", DictVectorizer(sort=False)),
                 ("clf", xgb.XGBClassifier(max_depth=3))
                ])



# Perform cross-validation
cross_val_scores = cross_val_score(pipeline, X, y, scoring="roc_auc", cv=3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is that you need to import those from sklearn:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
```

I also tried to replicate it and ran into some other issues, but I found the solution in this answer: [Sklearn_pandas in a pipeline returns TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52055658/sklearn-pandas-in-a-pipeline-returns-typeerror-builtin-function-or-method-obj)

Below is my full code:

```
# Import modules
import pandas as pd
from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper, CategoricalImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer, StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
import xgboost as xgb

# Create list of column names for kidney data: kidney_cols
kidney_cols = ['age', 'bp', 'sg', 'al', 'su', 'rbc', 'pc', 'pcc', 'ba', 'bgr',
               'bu', 'sc', 'sod', 'pot', 'hemo', 'pcv', 'wc', 'rc', 'htn', 'dm',
               'cad', 'appet', 'pe', 'ane', 'label']

# Load dataset: df_kidney
df_kidney = pd.read_csv('chronic_kidney_disease.csv', names=kidney_cols,
                        na_values='?')

# Replace label values with 0 (ckd) and 1
df_kidney['label'].replace({'ckd':0, 'notckd':1}, inplace=True)

# Define X and y: X, y
X, y = df_kidney.iloc[:, :-1], df_kidney['label'].values

# Define new column order for X: col_order
col_order = ['age', 'bp', 'sg', 'al', 'su', 'bgr', 'bu', 'sc', 'sod', 'pot',
             'hemo', 'pcv', 'wc', 'rc', 'rbc', 'pc', 'pcc', 'ba', 'htn', 'dm',
             'cad', 'appet', 'pe', 'ane']

# Rearrange columns of X
X = X[col_order]

# Create a boolean mask for categorical columns
categorical_feature_mask = X.dtypes == object

# Get a list of categorical column names
categorical_columns = X.columns[categorical_feature_mask].tolist()

# Get a list of non-categorical column names
non_categorical_columns = X.columns[~categorical_feature_mask].tolist()

# Create empty list to hold column imputers: transformers
transformers = []

# Create numeric imputers and add to list of transformers
transformers.extend([([num_col], [Imputer(strategy='median'),
                                                 StandardScaler()]) for num_col
                    in non_categorical_columns])

# Create categorical imputers and add to list of transformers
transformers.extend([(cat_col, [CategoricalImputer()]) for cat_col in
                    categorical_columns])

# Use list of transformers to create a DataFrameMapper object
numeric_categorical_union = DataFrameMapper(transformers, input_df=True,
                                            df_out=True)

# Define Dictifier class to turn df into dictionary as part of pipeline
class Dictifier(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):       
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return X.to_dict('records')

# Create full pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline([('featureunion', numeric_categorical_union),
                    ('dictifier', Dictifier()),
                    ('vectorizer', DictVectorizer(sort=False)),
                    ('clf', xgb.XGBClassifier(max_depth=3))])

# Perform cross-validation
cross_val_scores = cross_val_score(pipeline, X, y, scoring='roc_auc', cv=3)
```